# D3.js rollup on nesting operator with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a d3.js visualization for a time reporting application.
I have row data in an array *actuals* containing project time reports (simplified):

```
[{  resource: "John Smith",
    reporting_period: "2012/04/1",
    project: "Java implementation",
    hours: 8} 
 ... }]
```

I am trying to use the *d3.nest* operator to group the project actuals hierarchically by project, resource and period. Everything works great but I cannot find a way to get the subtotals of *hours* at the intermediate levels of the grouping using the *nest.rollup()* operator.

I have something like:

```
actuals_by_prj_rsrc_period = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d["project"]; })
        .key(function(d) { return d["resource"]; })
        .key(function(d) { return d["reporting_period"]; })
        .rollup(function(rows) {return {
            tot_hours:d3.sum(rows, function(d) {return d["hours"];}),
            actuals: rows
        };})
        .entries(actuals);
```

but it returns **tot_hours** only at the leaf level.
Any advice on how to approach this using only *d3.nest*?

Comment: What exactly do you want to compute `tot_hours`? Is it the aggregate number of hours across all previous reporting periods? Are you grouping by resource? By project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from docs:

> nest.rollup(function)
>
> Specifies a rollup function to be applied on each group of **leaf**
>   elements. The return value of the rollup function will replace the
>   array of **leaf values** in either the associative array returned by the
>   map operator, or the values attribute of each entry returned by the
>   entries operator.

As you can see rollup works with leaf elements. You could bypass this by having data nested at multiple levels:

```
function nest(keys, data, rollupFunc) {
    var nst = d3.nest();
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        nst.key(function(d) { return d[key]; });
    });
    if (rollupFunc) {
        nst.rollup(rollupFunc);
    }
    return nst.entries(data);
}

var rollupFunction = function(d) {
    return {
        "total_hours": d3.sum(d, function(dd) { return dd["hours"]})
    }
}

var rez1 = nest(["project", "resource"], actuals);
var rez2 = nest(["project"], actuals, rollupFunction);
var rez3 = nest(["project", "resource"], actuals, rollupFunction);
```

But this very inefficient for larger data sets. Otherwise I would suggest using `nest()` function to create all intermediate levels. Then you could aggregate total hours using your own recursive function. Pseudocode:

```
function aggregate(node) {
    if (node has property total_hours) {
        return total_hours
    }
    sum = 0
    foreach child in data.values {
        sum += aggregate(child)    
    }
    node.total_hours = sum
    return node.total_hours 
}
```